# Error: Invalid data; couldn't passe JSON object, array, or value

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, restful-url

I am having a problem when trying to make POST or PUT requests to Firebase RESTful API...
To make the request I am using Valve's Panorama JavaScript which execution is handled by Google V8 engine.

A GET request (which works without problems) looks like this:

```
$.AsyncWebRequest("https://<project>.firebaseio.com/-KrFV19WfaC7tfY6qys6.json",
        {
            type: "GET",
            complete: function (data){
                $.Msg("WOW: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (err){
                $.Msg("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            },
        });
```

And I get the response:

```
WOW: {"statusText":"success","responseText":"{\"a\":\"1\"}\u0000","status":200}
```

But when I try to do a PUT or POST request which code looks like this:

```
$.AsyncWebRequest("https://<project>.firebaseio.com/game.json",
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: {"A":"B"},
            success: function (data){
                $.Msg("WOW: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (err){
                $.Msg("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            },
        });
```

I get the next response:

```
Error: {"statusText":"error",
        "responseText":"{\n  \"error\" : \"Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.\"\n}\n\u0000",
        "status":400}
```

Can somebody help me understand what could be the problem?

Comment: what do you have in err? console.log (err)  ?

Comment: may be you can try logging only `data` not `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

According to [this piece of code](https://github.com/SwordBacon/DotaNextGen/blob/0fb2b9f12ef55b96f9283479394f94eb384e36d8/main/content/panorama/scripts/custom_game/statcollection.js)

you have to wrap your object in a `payload` property:

```
data: {payload: JSON.stringify({ "A": "B" })},
```

---

Have to tried to use `JSON.stringify()` around your request data object?

Like:

```
$.AsyncWebRequest("https://<project>.firebaseio.com/game.json",
    {
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"A":"B"}),
        success: function (data){
            $.Msg("WOW: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (err){
            $.Msg("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        },
    });
```

Also, is there a contentType property in `AsyncWebRequest`?

So maybe you have to add

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

to the request object (after the `type` property for example).

Comment: tried with both,
contentType doesn't resolve
JSON.stringify in data, results in panorama error, saying: !! (s2r://panorama/scripts/custom_game/heroselect.vjs_c, line:9, col:2) - data value for AsyncWebRequest settings must be an object with named key->value request params if set

Comment: if i stringify the data, it results in panorama error, it needs to be an object with named key->value

Comment: what happens when you try using jQuery - $.ajax(...) like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800923/firebase-rest-api-post-request-fails-with-error-invalid-data-couldnt-parse-j

Comment: sadly $ isn't pure jQuery or it isn't jQuary at all, so no ajax, just an imitation because it has only 16 functions: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Dota_2_Workshop_Tools/Panorama/Javascript/API#.24

Comment: Is this [page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Dota_2_Workshop_Tools/Panorama/Javascript/API) the only documentation for `AsyncWebRequest`?

Comment: Perhaps you can lookup the JS source code (browser dev tools) of `$.AsyncWebRequest` and see what happens inside the function? Perhaps `data` isn't the correct name of the property?

Comment: I can't find anything on AsyncWebRequest, but i looked up on GitHub and i see there are around 91 exemples where they use data

Comment: I've updated my answer. (probably not the solution though...)

Comment: I looked into it, and it looks like that "payload" property is actually for "getdotastats" API that those people are using, not actually need for the function to work, direct explanation from them how to use the function: [link](https://getdotastats.com/#source2__asyncwebrequest) 
copy-paste the function and changing the URL to my firebase, i get the same error