# Getting "Bad Request 400" when POSTing to Firebase Realtime Database in jQuery, but works using Postman

Tags: jquery, firebase, post, postman, http-status-code-400

Postman updates updates the real-time database perfectly. For example, when I POST {"address": 1} to https://[db_name].firebaseio.com/leads.json I get an update in the db. But when using jQuery:

```
var url = 
$.post('https://[db_name].firebaseio.com/leads.json', {"address": "1/4 Ross, Street"});
```

I get this error:

```
"POST https://[db_name].firebaseio.com/leads.json 400 (Bad Request) Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value"
```

According to [Google's list of error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data), this error means it's finding the server, not failing authentication (it's set to public), but an error with the REST API or PUT/POST request. But it works perfectly for Postman.

[EDIT]
Just tried this as well and received the same error:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800923/firebase-rest-api-post-request-fails-with-error-invalid-data-couldnt-parse-j/30802721):

```
var data = {"address": "1/4 Ross, Street"};
jQuery.ajax({
    accept: "application/json",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://[name].firebaseio.com/leads.json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```